# Angular Material 2 Tabs with fixed (sticky) tab labels

Tags: css, angular-material2

I have a layout using Angular Material 2 `mat-sidenav` layout with a mat-tab layout in the `mat-sidenav-content` section. I am trying to make the `mat-tab-labels` sticky so they are always visible, and still allow the dynamic tab-content to scroll. I can get the labels to stay fixed by setting `overflow: hidden` on the `mat-sidenav-content` and then set `overflow: scroll` on the `mat-tab-body-wrapper` element, but I have to set a fixed height to get the `tab-content` to scroll, but I have dynamic content so a fixed height isn't an option. Is there a way I can get my sticky labels and scrolling too without setting a fixed height?

Below is a demo. Shrink the vertical height of your window until it covers part of the "Large content" div. It will not scroll. Then uncomment the `mat-tab-group` css that sets a height and it will scroll as desired (but a fixed height).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rty6oe?file=app%2Fsidenav-fixed-example.css

**UPDATE**

Ok, @Dakota Maker's answer solved the immediate problem, and also reminded me of what I was originally trying to fix that brought me to the point of not being able to scroll. I updated my example app to reflect my real app better. I have a sub-header inside the sidenav-content area that sits above the mat-tab-group, and when scrolling it never gets to the bottom unless the window height is large enough because the header seems to have pushed the content down and off the screen. I can add a margin to the bottom of the content to compensate for the sub-header, but the sub-header area height can change.

If I should accept the answer to the original question and open a new question, please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `height:100%` one the `mat-tab-groups` and you will be able to scroll and there won't be a big white block in the middle of the large content

**EDIT TO ACCOMPANY OP's UPDATE:**

You can add something like `bottom:12px` to the `.mat-tab-body-wrapper` to give it a fixed amount of space at the bottom. This will end up giving you some of the overflow at the top of the wrapper some overlap with where the tabs are at, but you should be able to work that out also adding in something like `margin-top:12px` to the same block. Hope this helps out!

Comment: That solved the immediate problem, but please view my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Since the height is dynamic, I ended up creating a variable that would get updated with the current height of the sub-header when it changes and binding it to `margin-bottom` of the `.mat-tab-body-wrapper`.